# "Paintings on walls and ceilings" and "painting of portraits, landscapes"

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, hypernyms

I am creating a portfolio of painter's works and I need to categorize them.

There will be two global categories:

1. Paintings on canvas
2. Painting on walls and ceilings

The paintings on canvas divide into "Portraits", "Landscapes", and so on.

How should I call paintings of walls and ceilings in English?

Maybe there is some precise word? I haven't found it, using translators from Russian.

Comment: Consider [*mural*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mural) or [*fresco*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fresco?show=0&t=1347120105). Here are some other types of [*wall painting*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresco#Other_types_of_wall_painting).

Comment: Also note that there is a difference between *paintings* **of** *walls* and *paintings* **on** *walls*.  The former means the subject of the painting is a wall, while the latter means the paint was applied to a wall.

Comment: @Jim sorry, just a typo. :)

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits In that case, please consider editing your own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are called [murals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mural).

> A mural is any piece of artwork painted or applied directly on a wall, ceiling or other large permanent surface. A particularly distinguishing characteristic of mural painting is that the architectural elements of the given space are harmoniously incorporated into the picture.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but actually not every wall-painting can be called "mural", but only if it was painted on a wet plaster. Maybe there is more general term for all wall-paintings?

Comment: Every wall painting is a mural.  It is a "fresco" only if painted on wet plaster.

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits I'm sure you know more about this subject than I do, but is it possible, as coleopterist's link explains, that *mural* applies to any wall painting, *fresco* refers to what you describe and *secco* refers to painting on dry walls? I defer to your expertise on the subject.

Comment: OK, seems, you are right. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score 3):

The word you are looking for is ***mural***, which per the OED is

> A painting executed on a wall or ceiling as part of a scheme of decoration.
>
> Etymology: a. Fr. *muraille*: Com. Rom. *muralia* (repr. L. *mūrālia* neut. pl. of *mūrālis* mural a., taken as fem. sing.: see **-al**<sup>1 5</sup>); cf. Sp. *muralla*, Pg. *muralha*, Ital. *muraglia*; also OFr. *murail*, Pr. *muralh* masc.